# How to retrieve a variable from http.conf using PHP

Tags: php, apache

How can one retrieve a varibale for instance alias /MyDirectory/ "C:/MyDirectory/MyDirectory/" from http.conf using PHP. Is there an easier way than to open http.conf and read it line by line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read single lines from a file. But why would you want to tinker with your server settings from your program?

```
$handle = fopen('httpd.conf', 'r');
if($handle) {
    while($buffer = fgets($handle) !== false) {
        // do something with the data you read
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo 'An error occured';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```